# Why aren't images found in Google App Engine project (Java, not using GWT)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've found other questions using Python and app.yaml, but I'm working in Java using Eclipse.  I've tried every permutation I could possibly think of including forward slashes, backslashes, opening with dots.  I've tried putting the image itself in the root directory of the project.  I've found similar questions on here, but they usually referenced an app.yaml.  I know this should be very simple, but nothing I've tried has worked.  I'm sure that I'm missing something in a configuration file somewhere.  This is the first App Engine app I've tried, so I'm still feeling my way around it.

This tag:

```
<img src="images/CTT_placeholder.png" />
```

Yields this warning:

```
Jun 03, 2014 12:53:13 PM om.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet     doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /images/CTT_placeholder.png
```

The images folder is in the root of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create `images` directory in the `war` directory of your project

```
/war/images
```

and put your images there. Then your tag will work:

```
<img src="images/CTT_placeholder.png" />
```

Comment: Boom!  I knew it had to be something simple.  Thanks, Andrei.  I would vote you up if I had the rep.